# Sort list of dictionaries by multiple keys with different ordering

Tags: python, list, sorting, python-2.7, dictionary

I need sort this list of dictionaries:

```
[ {K: 1, B: 2, A: 3, Z: 4, ... } , ... ]
```

Ordering should be:

- K - descending
- B - descending
- A - ascending
- Z - ascending

I only found out how to sort all keys in ascending or descending (`reverse=True`):

```
stats.sort(key=lambda x: (x['K'], x['B'], x['A'], x['Z']))
```

Can anybody help, how to sort in key-different ordering?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

if you have numbers as values, you can use this:

```
stats.sort(key=lambda x: (-x['K'], -x['B'], x['A'], x['Z']))
```

For general values:

```
stats.sort(key=lambda x: (x['A'], x['Z']))
stats.sort(key=lambda x: (x['K'], x['B']), reverse=True)
```

Comment: Is there solution for string values too?