# Python sorting list of dictionary

Tags: python

I have a list of dictionary like below,

```
x = [
   {"matches_count": 10, distance: 50},
   {"matches_count": 20, distance: 50},
   {"matches_count": 1, "distance: 20},
   {"matches_count": 2, "distance": 20},
   {"matches_count": 5, "distance: 30},
]
```

I need to sort this like below

```
x = [
  {"matches_count": 2, distance: 20},
  {"matches_count": 1, "distance: 20},
  {"matches_count": 5, "distance: 30},
  {"matches_count": 20, distance: 50},
  {"matches_count": 10, "distance": 50} 
]
```

Basically, this should be sort with both **distance** and the **matches_count**. When the distance is the same the highest matches count should come first. Is there any possibility to do this with the **sorted** method? Or is there any other way to perform this?

I have checked the below questions and I did not able to get proper insight from them for my question.
[Sort list of dictionaries by multiple keys with different ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18761776/sort-list-of-dictionaries-by-multiple-keys-with-different-ordering)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I sort a list of dictionaries by a value of the dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72899/how-do-i-sort-a-list-of-dictionaries-by-a-value-of-the-dictionary) and [Sort list of lists ascending and then descending](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6666748/4518341)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `sorted` function:

```
print(sorted(x, key=lambda a: (a['distance'], -a['matches_count'])))
```

Output:

```
[{'matches_count': 2, 'distance': 20}, {'matches_count': 1, 'distance': 20}, {'matches_count': 5, 'distance': 30}, {'matches_count': 20, 'distance': 50}, {'matches_count': 10, 'distance': 50}]
```

This sorts by first the `distance` key, and if it's the same, it sorts by the negative of the `matches_count`. I make it negative so it sorts in a descending order instead of an ascending order.

Answer (score 2):

You can just sort by a key, where the key is a tuple and you flip the sign of matches count. This will sort first by distance ascending, then matches descending.

```py
x.sort(key=lambda e: (e["distance"], -e["matches_count"]))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
x = [
    {"matches_count": 10, "distance": 50},
    {"matches_count": 20, "distance": 50},
    {"matches_count": 1, "distance": 20},
    {"matches_count": 2, "distance": 20},
    {"matches_count": 5, "distance": 30},
]

x.sort(key=lambda k: (k['distance'], -k['matches_count']))

for e in x:
    print(e)
```